# ZeroMQ is not working over unicast IPv6

Tags: c++, sockets, ipv6, zeromq

I'm in a trouble with ZeroMQ and IPv6. When I use a connection through IPv4 or if I use "tcp://[::1]:5558", it connects like a charm. However, if I use the server full IPv6 address (on my local host or remote host) it connects, but don't get data on the other endpoint.

Here is my code sample:

*client.cpp*

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <zmq.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    void* context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void* socket = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    int ipv6 = 1;
    zmq_setsockopt(socket, ZMQ_IPV6, &ipv6, 4);
    zmq_connect(socket, "tcp://[fe80::52e5:49ff:fef8:dbc6]:5558");
    //zmq_connect(socket, "tcp://[::1]:5558");
    zmq_setsockopt(socket, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "pub", 3);

    zmq_msg_t message;
    do {
        zmq_msg_init (&message);
        zmq_msg_recv (&message, socket, 0);
        printf("%s\n", (char*)zmq_msg_data(&message));
        zmq_msg_close(&message);
    } while (zmq_msg_more(&message));
}
```

And *server.cpp*

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <zmq.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    void* context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void* publisher = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);
    int ipv6 = 1;
    zmq_setsockopt(publisher, ZMQ_IPV6, &ipv6, sizeof(int));

    zmq_bind(publisher, "tcp://*:5558");

    char buffer[4] = "pub";
    unsigned tries = 0;

    while(tries < 10) {
        zmq_send(publisher, &buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
        tries++;
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using ZeroMQ 4.0.0 RC, but it is also happening on 3.2. I'm on linux (slackware) and installed it from sources. I also tested using a java server using jeroMQ and the problem is the same. I did another test using a REQ-REP connection and the problem is the same.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: At this point, you probably need to do some debugging. You could use tcpdump to figure out if packets are being sent (and received on the other side_ or not. In addition, you can look at the output of "ss -tpan" to see if there are any incoming packets on the server connection. Lastly, I would recommend investigating the " netstat -s -p tcp" to see if can spot anything wrong using the TCP stats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fe80*` addresses are link local, you must specify the local hosts link name: e.g. `fe80...:1%eth1`

> fe80::/10 — Addresses in the link-local prefix are only valid and
>   unique on a single link. Within this prefix only one subnet is
>   allocated (54 zero bits), yielding an effective format of fe80::/64.
>   The least significant 64 bits are usually chosen as the interface
>   hardware address constructed in modified EUI-64 format. A link-local
>   address is required on every IPv6-enabled interface—in other words,
>   applications may rely on the existence of a link-local address even
>   when there is no IPv6 routing. These addresses are comparable to the
>   auto-configuration addresses 169.254.0.0/16 of IPv4.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Local_addresses

Comment: Thank you very much! I am a damn noob on IPv6. It solves my issue!